# Most valid way for the URL html structure

Tags: html, seo

I'm building my own theme, and trying to create links to articles this way:

```
<a href="URL"><img src="THUMB" /><div>TIME_STAMP</div><h3>THE_TITLE</h3></a>
```

But sometimes Google index my posts with the `TIME_STAMP` showing before the title in the search results.

What is the best structure/tags/attributes to tell Search Engines to read `THE_TITLE` as the explicit title of the post and ignore any surrounding text?

Answer (score 3):

There are different ways to achieve this. Google tries to automatically extract the publish date of an article you wrote. The most common and easiest way for Google is to use rich snippets: http://schema.org/Article
See "datePublished" - property for this.

After you implemented these little HTML-snippets you can test your markup using the Rich Snippet Testing Tool: https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/

Comment: Yes, but what if I want to add any other pseudos before the title not just the date? Say a label such as 'fixed' or 'new', and I don't want to Google to index them.

Comment: @AhmedSaad You could use absolute positioning on an element much further down in the markup. Or use CSS pseduo `:before` or `:after` content.

Comment: You cannot explicitely exclude parts of your source code to be excluded. Use CSS or your own HTML markup and CSS to separate `THE_TITLE` from the other elements you will use.
I would use a different HTML markup as you showed in your example:
<div class="article">
   <img class="THUMB" src="path/to/img.jpg" />
   <h3>
      <span class="newBadge"></span>
      <span class="date">TIME_STAMP</span>
      <a href="URL" title="THE_TITLE">THE_TITLE</a>
   </h3>
</div><!-- / .article -->
</code>
I would not put heading-tags as children of an a-tag.

Comment: Ok, so I didn't manage to format the comment nicely, sorry for that. Remove the `</code>` from it.